# Similarity between two geometric shapes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, computer-vision

I have two shapes in a 2D space, not necessarily convex, and I'd like to compare how similar they are. How can I define a robust distance metric to measure their similarity, and how can I compute it?

[image: Distance between two shapes]

I am looking for a method which provides a short distance in case of:

1. scaling;
2. rotation;
3. perhaps local scaling or rotation.

---

I see two possible solutions:

1. transform the shapes into **pixel-based matrices** (bitmap) and compute a Levenshtein distance (but without enough robustness in the distance, in case of rotation for instance);
2. transform the shapes into **graphs** and try to define a distance between them.

Comment: *Computing* the distance is probably not the issue here; you need to define *what* the distance is first! Is that your question, or do you have some idea (but not included it in the question)? Note that there are many, many possible distances between curves/shapes (min, max, avg, median, min max, max min, ...)

Comment: My question was about defining a metric more than computing it, sorry for the misunderstanding. Thanks @D.W. for your clarification.

Comment: The distance should be robust to *what* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use SIFT (or SURF, or other similar methods) to align one object to the other to account for scaling and rotation, and then compute a pixelwise distance based on the aligned images.

The right algorithm to use for alignment will depend upon the nature of the 2D images.  If they are natural-color photographs taken using a camera, SIFT, SURF, etc. might work well.  If they are black-and-white geometric shapes like shown in the question, you might do better to use image moments (e.g., Hu moments) or some other approach.

Comment: May be "Shape context" descriptor (http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html) suits better for this  purpose. Also it has been already implemented in OpenCV - http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html

Comment: @old-ufo, great suggestion!  How about posting an answer with that suggestion (and ideally a brief description of it), so I and others can upvote it?

Comment: These point detectors/descriptors are useful for shape registration and will not work well in case of dissimilar shapes. They do not define a similarity measure.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Good point. I agree with your criticism.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @D.W.: well, the OP seems satisfied...